# how to extract unique words from cell and count them

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an column `"DESCRIPTION" (VARCHAR2 (500 Byte))`

I want as result two columns. First extract from each cell unique words and display them in one column, and in second count their frequency.

Additionaly I have limiting parametre `"ENTRYDATE" (i.e. "WHERE ENTRYDATE BETWEEN 20180101 and 20190101").` Because table is quite big.

I have some solution in Excel, but it's messy and painful to do.

Is it even possible to do in Oracle with SELECT?

Example:

NUMBER OF COLUMN | EXPLANATION

```
1 | roses are red violets are blue
2 | red violets 
3 | red
4 | roses
5 | blue
```

RESULT:

```
WORDS | COUNTING

roses | 2
are | 2
red | 3
violets | 2
blue | 2
```

Variation of query:

```
with test as
      (select 1 as nor, 'roses are red violets are blue' as explanation from dual union all
       select 2 as nor, 'red violets' as explanation from dual union all
       select 3 as nor, 'red'  as explanation from dual union all
       select 4 as nor, 'roses'  as explanation from dual union all
       select 5 as nor, 'blue'   as explanation from dual
      ),
    temp as
      (select nor,
             trim(column_value) word
      from test join xmltable(('"' || replace(explanation, ' ', '","') ||'"')) on 1 = 1
     )
   select word,
          count(*)
   from temp
   group by word
   order by word;
```

returns ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex, show us sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: EXPLANATION

roses are red violets are blue
red
red
roses
blue

RESULT:

WORDS | COUNTING
roses | 2
are | 2
red | 3
violets | 1
blue | 2

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your old Oracle version. This query should work, it has only basic `connect by`, `instr` and `dbms_random`:

```
select word, count(1) counting
  from (
    select id, trim(case pos2 when 0 then substr(description, pos1) 
                              else substr(description, pos1, pos2 - pos1) 
                    end) word
      from (
        select id, description, 
               case level when 1 then 1 else instr(description, ' ', 1, level - 1) end pos1, 
               instr(description, ' ', 1, level) pos2
          from t 
          connect by prior dbms_random.value is not null 
                 and prior id = id 
                 and level <= length(description) - length(replace(description, ' ', '')) + 1))
  group by word
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=903d2b0d4eac581dfc33df69ae081b2f)</sup>**

Comment: It works) But works a bit slow even on test environment, where i can put in query limit by one day (ENTRYDATE = 20180101)?

Comment: Add `where entrydate = 20180101`  in inner query, like in this [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=16fa9bf19a14bdf2a202bb43251996a6).

Answer (score 1):

Split explanation into rows (so that you'd get *words*), then apply `COUNT` function to those words.

```
SQL> with test (nor, explanation) as
  2    (select 1, 'roses are red violets are blue' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'red violets'                    from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'red'                            from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'roses'                          from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'blue'                           from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    (select nor,
 10            regexp_substr(explanation, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) word
 11     from test join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                                        connect by level <= regexp_count(explanation, ' ') + 1
 13                                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) on 1 = 1
 14    )
 15  select word,
 16         count(*)
 17  from temp
 18  group by word
 19  order by word;

WORD                             COUNT(*)
------------------------------ ----------
are                                     2
blue                                    2
red                                     3
roses                                   2
violets                                 2

SQL>
```

You mentioned `entrydate` column but there's none in your sample data so - if necessary, include it into the `TEMP` CTE.

### Edit

Huh, Oracle 9i ... back to the Dark Ages:

```
SQL> with test (nor, explanation) as
  2    (select 1, 'roses are red violets are blue' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'red violets'                    from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'red'                            from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'roses'                          from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'blue'                           from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    (select nor,
 10            trim(column_value) word
 11     from test join xmltable(('"' || replace(explanation, ' ', '","') ||'"')) on 1 = 1
 12    )
 13  select word,
 14         count(*)
 15  from temp
 16  group by word
 17  order by word;

WORD                   COUNT(*)
-------------------- ----------
are                           2
blue                          2
red                           3
roses                         2
violets                       2

SQL>
```

Comment: set sqlnumber off

Comment: I prefer seeing line numbers because it is easier to point to something in code you write. Also, if there's an error saying "error in line 27" - which line is line 27? But - yes, in this case, that would make sense. Thank you for the comment, @akk0rd87.

Comment: I prefer use this option cuz it's very easy to copy my code and run it by someone else.

Comment: Query returns ORA-00904: "REGEXP_COUNT": invalid identifier. Maybe due to old version of oracle? (11g)

Comment: Clarification: not even 11g, rather Oracle 9.2.0.5.0.

Comment: Modify CONNECT BY clause to this: `connect by level <= length(explanation) - length(replace(explanation, ' ', '')) + 1`. Any improvement?

Comment: After modifying like this, it returns "ORA-00904: "EXPLANATION": invalid identifier". Furthemore as I tried regexp_substr dont work on Oracle 9 too.

Comment: I don't even remember what 9i had (or didn't have). I edited my answer by adding the XMLTABLE option; hopefully, it'll work as expected.

Comment: If I run as it is in Ora 9 it returns: "ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing". I modified it a bit (added to main post) and now it returns: "ORA-00905: missing keyword". I hope we almost there :)

Comment: Try to switch to old, comma-separated tables in the FROM clause, i.e. `from test, xmltable(...)` instead of explicit JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Oracle 12c+
with test (nor, explanation) as (
select 1, 'roses are red violets are blue' from dual union all
select 2, 'red violets'                    from dual union all
select 3, 'red'                            from dual union all
select 4, 'roses'                          from dual union all
select 5, 'blue'                           from dual)
select regexp_substr(explanation, '\S+', 1, lvl) word, count(*) cnt
from test,
lateral(
select rownum lvl
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(explanation, '\S+')
)
group by regexp_substr(explanation, '\S+', 1, lvl);

WORD                                  CNT
------------------------------ ----------
roses                                   2
are                                     2
violets                                 2
red                                     3
blue                                    2
```

Comment: "ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing" Mine oracle version is 11g.